# Does anyone knows the origin of the Maunder Minimum and Dalton minimum?

Tags: fundamental-astronomy

Solar spots seams to be a good indicator of solar activity. Does anyone know the reason for the Maunder and Dalton minima?

Comment: Props to anyone who can answer this.   My understanding is that the cause isn't known, but it's observed that the sun spends about 15% of the time in a grand minimum and observations of other stars agrees with that estimate.   I don't know of and I've never seen a good explanation for precisely why the sunspot cycle enters periods of grand minimum.   Source on the 15%:  https://www.forbes.com/sites/brucedorminey/2014/01/20/sun-flatlining-into-grand-minimum-says-solar-physicist/#7aad368718de

Comment: I would be very interested in knowing whether  other stars with spots have also planets around.

Comment: @luisblasCabrera We have definitely found stars with planets that also have sun spots. This is pretty much true of almost every M Dwarf that has planets. M Dwarfs can have huge sunspots and as such, it can actually be a challenge to separate out detections of planets from sunspots.

Comment: Tank you @zephyr and. Calculations show me that sun spots and storms seemed to be strongly related  to the solar system evolution.